# Combining custom Python log handlers

Tags: python, logging, twitter, python-2.7

I'm write a short script that periodically polls a website, and tweets the result of the polling.

I thought it clever to use python's built in logging mechanism to do this:

```
# Main Script
twitter_handler = TwitterHandler(config=args.get('twitter-config'))
logger.addHandler(twitter_handler)

logger.debug('Debug', extra={'tweet': True})

# Handler
class TwitterHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, config=None):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        # Do whatever setup is necessary

    def emit(self, record):
        if getattr(record, 'tweet', False):
            # tweet
```

I would also like to introduce more complex log handling, like only tweeting so often if conditions haven't changed.

At that point, I thought I should probably separate this into three types of handlers to decouple them:

- `TweetHandler`: To actually tweet messages
- `ConditionalHandler`: To only log when some condition is met
- `PeriodicHandler`: To only log according to some periodic rules

Supposing I break apart the functionality into those different handlers, how can I combine them? Some sort of meta-class or class decorator?

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but this seems like a pretty weird use of `logging`... what advantage is there of using `logging` to solve this problem, rather than just writing directly to Twitter from your main code?

Comment: In previous attempts, I just had a `twitter_messaging` object and embedded it where necessary in the main script. I didn't want to couple that to the code, or require that it be present, so I was investigating how it might work if I leveraged python's built in logging.